# mips gnu toolchain with glibc_2.13

Tags: mips, glibc, tizen

I am trying to load few modules onto Tizen on my MIPS-based platform. Currently, I am using sourcery codebench gnu linux compiler. The libc.so files it uses have version 2.17 which libc.so file on my platform has version 2.13. I need a toolchain which has a version less than or equal to 2.13 and supports MIPS.

Thanks,
Atchyut Sreekar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few options:

1. talk to the Tizen people to see if they have pre-compiled toolchains that match your system
2. build the code directly on the device
3. use [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) to build a new cross-compiler but with an old glibc version
4. upgrade your system because glibc-2.13 (and glibc-2.17 for that matter) are ridiculously old and have a large number of known security vulnerabilities including remote exploits.  developing & deploying anything based on those glibc versions is a terrible terrible mistake.

Comment: the problem is tizen didnt add support for mips architecture yet. one of my team mates tried building the code on the device but apparently it failed (we are building modules for hw acceleration). i just started trying with buildroot.. i'll try it with crosstool also.. thanks man..

Comment: i assumed you wanted to maintain compatibility w/Tizen, but if you can go with a complete system w/buildroot, that'd be a great alternative.

Comment: thanks man.. crosstool worked like magic.. once the pressure of deadline is done.. we'll look into upgrading the system..